# flutter_local_notification: getting the time of scheduled notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications

I am using flutter_local_notification and want to see (for testing and verification purposes) the time at which the notification is scheduled.

Once a notification is scheduled, how can I find out when it is scheduled? I can easily get the notification id(s), title, or body, but I cannot figure out how to get the exact time a notification is scheduled for.

Also, if you can share any recommendations or best practices for testing notifications that would be greatly appreciated.

I have read through the documentation for Flutter local notification and searched online. I have also tried various methods and still have not been able to find a solution.